# gnuradio companion: "sources" tree does not appear in blocks menu in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnu

Ubuntu 18.04.

I have done the following:

```
sudo apt install gnuradio
sudo apt install gr-osmosdr
sudo apt install hackrf
sudo apt install libhackrf-dev
```

Following the gnuradio tutorial here:

https://greatscottgadgets.com/sdr/1/

After launching gnuradio companion, I am unable to add a source as "sources" does not appear in the blocks menu.

Answer (score 0):

"Sources" was under the "no module specified" branch.